# qt4 - change the color of text cursor in a qlineedit?

Tags: colors, cursor, qt4, paintevent

I've subclassed qlineedit and written a custom line edit which has a default text. The default text is grayed out until the user starts to write some text into it. also the line edit has a time mask input. it only accepts inputs in range of 23:59:59.

**the problem** is when the line edit is empty and the default text is displayed in gray color, the cursor is also gray. I'd like to know how i'm able to change the cursor color to black while the default text is in gray color.

I have tried to override the paintevent. i saw the source code of qlineedit and saw that the QLineControl::DrawCursor is responsible for drawing the cursor in paintevent. but i have no idea how to change the pen color so it can effect the cursor color. Any ideas on how to do that? tnx.

```
 void QCustomLineEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * pe)
 {
    QLineEdit::paintEvent(pe);
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::red);
    painter.end();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`QLineEdit` has a property named `placeholderText` which you can use to set the grayed text to be displayed when there is no text in the edit box. The cursor color is not changed and when you start typing the placeholder text disappears.

[image]

Comment: yes i'm aware of that property. I didn't use the property and rewrite my own qlineEdit, becuase i wanted that every time the cursor was back in 0 position, the default text appears again. but using this property doesn't give me the feature i want.